# I get connection error 8017 while trying to use Fast Load tool

Tags: database-connection, teradata

I receive error message 8017:

> The UserId, Password or account is invalid while trying to load data
>   using fast load.

Fast Load Script:

```
logon 10.61.59.93/796207,Wpwp123;

drop table DATAMDL_SNDBX.QA_FL_PD;

drop table DATAMDL_SNDBX.ERROR_TABLE_ucv; 

drop table DATAMDL_SNDBX.ERROR_TABLE_TV;

CREATE SET TABLE DATAMDL_SNDBX.QA_FL_PD ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
      NAME VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      INITIAL VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC)
PRIMARY INDEX CRO_FLIGHT_LEG_DEP_NUPI ( NAME );

SET RECORD VARTEXT'~';

DEFINE
NAME (VARCHAR(10)),
INITIAL (VARCHAR(10))

FILE = C:\Users\Scarlet\Desktop\FL_Data.TXT;

BEGIN LOADING DATAMDL_SNDBX.QA_FL_PD ERRORFILES teradata fastload.ERROR_TABLE_UCV, teradata fastload.ERROR_TABLE_TV;

INSERT INTO DATAMDL_SNDBX.QA_FL_PD
VALUES (:NAME,
        :INITIAL);

END LOADING;
LOGOFF;
```

File containing data (with only 1 record):

```
NAME~INITIAL
PRASHANT~PD
```

Error Message:

```
C:\Windows\system32>cd\

C:\>fastload<C:\Users\Scarlet\Desktop\FL_Script.TXT
     ===================================================================
     =                                                                 =
     =          FASTLOAD UTILITY     VERSION 14.10.00.03               =
     =          PLATFORM WIN32                                         =
     =                                                                 =
     ===================================================================

     ===================================================================
     =                                                                 =
     =          Copyright 1984-2013, Teradata Corporation.             =
     =          ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.                                   =
     =                                                                 =
     ===================================================================

**** 14:08:03 Processing starting at: Thu Mar 10 14:08:02 2016

     ===================================================================
     =                                                                 =
     =          Logon/Connection                                       =
     =                                                                 =
     ===================================================================

0001 logon 10.61.59.93/796207,

**** 14:08:03 RDBMS error 8017: The UserId, Password or Account is
              invalid.
**** 14:08:03 Unable to log on Main SQL Session
**** 14:08:03 FastLoad cannot continue. Exiting.
     ===================================================================
     =                                                                 =
     =          Exiting                                                =
     =                                                                 =
     ===================================================================

**** 14:08:03 Total processor time used = '0.124801 Seconds'
     .        Start : Thu Mar 10 14:08:02 2016
     .        End   : Thu Mar 10 14:08:03 2016
     .        Highest return code encountered = '12'.
**** 14:08:03 FDL4818 FastLoad Terminated
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect us to help you with this...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, I should have mentioned what mechanism I should be using to connect.
Adding below line at the top solved my problem

**logmech LDAP;**

Problem solved.. :)
I do not know how to close this thread.

Thanks
Prashant